Joint Central Moments of Bivariate Lognormal Distribution
Suppose X and Y are two variables bivariate lognormally (BVLN) distributed such that $ (X, Y) \sim BVLN (\theta_1, \theta_2, {\sigma_1}^2, {\sigma_2}^2, \rho) $. Then what is the joint central moment $ (\mu_{rs} = E[(X - E(X))^r (Y - E(Y))^s]) $? Is there any expression for this or some recursion relation?
Also I found here math.stackexchange.com the mixed raw moments but I need the mixed central moment. If there's some relationship between bivariate central moments and raw moments then that will help too.
